# How to install ejabberd in centOS 6.7?

Tags: xcode, centos, ejabberd

i am trying to install ejabberd in centos.

but i am getting an error "yum Ejabberd Install = no package found".

can you please answer ?

Comment: The correct syntax would be `yum install ejabberd`. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: yes. i used this.but not working

Answer (score 1):

You can download official installers and packages from ProcessOne website: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Comment: i want to set up it in live server.please give me solution for that..
if possible then tell me step for that

Comment: Well, download installer or package on your server and either run the binary installer or use centos command-line to install the package. This is really basic stuff.

Comment: could not found any feasible solution for this